# Being banned from questions and how to get people to change their vote after fixing the questions

Tags: support, down-votes, post-ban

I got downvoted on a few posts; despite having an overall positive question rating, I do have a few poor and downvoted questions. I took the time to fix them; however, people who downvoted won't take the time to recant their vote or explain why they won't recant their vote. Is there no way to go about getting unbanned from asking questions?

Comment: I only see two questions with a negative score. Have you deleted any questions?

Comment: The people who originally voted are unlikely to come back. Other people may upvote however. Editing bumps the post and may draw other people attention to it

Comment: Only one that received two downvotes; It was deleted because I was afraid of receiving more downvotes on it despite making fixes. (I realize the votes still count but adding more to it from people who aren't going to change their votes after making my fixes doesn't help).

Comment: @RichardTingle I was unaware that editing bumped the posts; thanks for that info.

Comment: Any questions that were deleted, perhaps not by you? Because with the posts I see, and one deleted post I am somewhat surprised that would have resulted a ban. Did you look at your recently deleted questions?

Comment: Ah yes; there are several deleted; but only a cumulative total of -4 in downvotes. @Bart

Comment: so I have -4 in downvotes from deleted questions, and -3 from active questions.

Comment: Is there any way in which you can improve those deleted posts and undelete them? (Or have them undeleted after improvement) If that is all there is, it might not take much.

Comment: Deleting too many questions can lead to a question ban regardless of votes on those questions.

Comment: You had 12 self-deleted questions. That's quite a bit, and it does weigh against you. I undeleted 11 of them, which should get you out of the ban by itself. I'd still take a little time to clean those up, though.

Comment: @BradLarson I was unaware that deleted questions counted towards the ban if they had no up or down votes. Thanks for this; that did the trick and I will work on editing those questions.